# Getting an error on configuring Vim: uint32_t check not defined correctly

Tags: vim, configuration

I've used the `configure` command a thousand times yet had never run into this and I can't seem to understand what the issue is.

Here is my `configure` command:

```
./configure --enable-multibyte --enable-perlinterp=dynamic --enable-rubyinterp=dynamic --with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic --with-python-config-dir=/usr/bin/python --enable-python3interp=dynamic --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin --enable-cscope --enable-gui=auto --with-features=huge --enable-fontset --enable-largefile --disable-netbeans --with-compiledby="Eytan Anjel" --enable-fail-if-missing
```

Everything goes through well until I hit this:

`checking uint32_t is 32 bits... configure: error: WRONG!  uint32_t not defined correctly.`

What I have tried:

1. I've tried to look into the code defining the integer (after checking multiple online sources) but there didn't seem to be an issue there.
2. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode, and Xcode Developer Tools
3. Tried to remove and reinstall vim

None of these worked. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have basically removed everything vim related from the computer and reinstalled vim. It fixed the issue but not sure why it was caused in the first place

Answer (score 0):

try to use `./configure CC=gcc`  before running make(1). I tried to run make(1) directly without configure it. and I had the same bug. After running configure it is ok to build now